# Scrapy not getting results from a custom searchbox

Tags: javascript, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to get scrapy to load a page from an intranet site and run a search using the webpages searchbox, once complete I will pass control to a second code block to do some work.

The search box uses Javascript which loads a new url with the search results. My spider though doesn't seem to be able to use the box. I've been looking around at a few tutorials on this and it should be right but I am not getting any luck.
I am just getting a blank output.

Expected output should be a full page returned with my search result, I then grab the h4 elements text value.

**Target Box Code**

```
<div class="searchbox">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var completeUrl = '/example/web/example.m4n';
</script>
<input type="text" name="_shellA" size="17" maxlength="40" id="searchfield" class="searchfield" value="Search" onfocus="if (value=='Search'){value=''}else{partHighlight(this.id,0,this.value.length)}" onblur="if (value==''){value='Search'};lostFocus()" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autoComplete(event);" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 27) {onEscape();return false;} if(UI.getKeyFrom(event)==13) {UI.elem('_shellA_sch0').onclick(); return false;} removeNewLines(this)"><input type="button" value="" id="_shellA_A" name="_shellA_A" class="searchbutton" onclick="if( UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click') ) {} return false;"><div class="autosuggestions invisible" id="autosuggestions"></div>
</div>
```

**My Code to target the search box**

```
class MegascraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'megascraper'
    allowed_domains = 'http://example.com'
    start_urls = ['http://example.com']
    def search_product(self, response):

        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url = 'http://example.com', formdata = '1111774', callback = self.something) #formdata is the data we are sending

    #If the search finds our value, pass control to this section
    def something(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')   #Use the HTML Parser
        print("something something")
        print(soup.find("h4").text)
```

Comment: Expected output should be a full page returned with my search result, I then grab the h4 elements text value.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help if you could provide the website link. Anyway, you should inspect the network calls that your browser does when you click in the search button and do the same request in your spider. Open "developer tools", go to the "network" tab, and then click the search box.

Comment: If I do it in my broweser it returns http://example.com/builder?build-query=Item123&seid=test1-products&viewMode=3  which is the url that shows the products I searched for.